# getContentPane().getUIPanel() doesn't display the contents

Tags: java

Problemas en esta línea: `frmLupe.getContentPane().add(getUIPanel(), "South");` abre el form pero `doesn't display the contents.`

cuando ejecuto mi programa me da error de lectura:

> read: Can't read input file!

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.geom.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
    import javax.swing.event.*; 

    public class Magnifying  {

        JFrame frmLupe = new JFrame();
        MagnifierPanel magnifierPanel; 
        MagnifierControl control; 
        private final LineBorder border = new LineBorder(Color.RED,1);
        private Point initialClick;
        JMenuBar JMenuMagnifying = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu JMenuMagnifying1 = new JMenu();
        JMenu JMenuMagnifying2 = new JMenu(); 
        JMenu JMenuMagnifying3 = new JMenu();
        JLabel JlImagen = new JLabel();
        JPanel PImagen = new JPanel();

        public void Magnifying(BufferedImage pic){

           (pic.getScaledInstance(pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)); 
            JlImagen.setIcon(icon);
            JlImagen.repaint();
            PImagen.add(JlImagen);
            frmLupe.add(PImagen);


            frmLupe.setUndecorated(true);
            frmLupe.getRootPane().setBorder(border);
            frmLupe.setFocusable(true);
            //frmLupe.getContentPane().add(getUIPanel(), "South"); <--ERROR AQUI
            frmLupe.getContentPane().add(JMenuMagnifying, BorderLayout.NORTH );
            frmLupe.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(magnifierPanel));
            frmLupe.setSize(620,650);
            frmLupe.setLocation(370,100);
            frmLupe.setVisible(true);


            JMenuMagnifying.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35,35));   
            JMenuMagnifying.add(JMenuMagnifying1);
            JMenuMagnifying.add(JMenuMagnifying2);
            JMenuMagnifying.add(JMenuMagnifying3);  

javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconos/verde_c.png")));
            JMenuMagnifying1.setToolTipText("Minimize window");
            JMenuMagnifying1.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){ 
                    frmLupe.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                }
            });


            JMenuMagnifying2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconos/amarillo_c.png"))); 
            JMenuMagnifying2.setToolTipText("Maximize window");
            JMenuMagnifying2.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){ 
                    frmLupe.setExtendedState(frmLupe.getExtendedState()| FramePrincipal.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                }
            });


            JMenuMagnifying3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconos/rojo_c.png")));
            JMenuMagnifying3.setToolTipText("Close window"); 
            JMenuMagnifying3.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){ 
                    frmLupe.setVisible(false); 
                }
            });


            frmLupe.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                     initialClick = e.getPoint();
                     frmLupe.getComponentAt(initialClick); 
                }
            });

            frmLupe.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                //se localiza la ventana
                int thisX = frmLupe.getLocation().x;
                int thisY = frmLupe.getLocation().y;

                //se determina el movimiento del mouse
                int xMoved = (thisX + e.getX()) - (thisX + initialClick.x);
                int yMoved = (thisY + e.getY()) - (thisY + initialClick.y);

                //se mueve la ventana
                int X = thisX + xMoved;
                int Y = thisY + yMoved;
                frmLupe.setLocation(X, Y); 
            }
          });
             magnifierPanel = new MagnifierPanel(pic); 
            control = new MagnifierControl(magnifierPanel);
            magnifierPanel.addMouseListener(control);
            magnifierPanel.addMouseMotionListener(control);
        }

        private JPanel getUIPanel(){

            final JLabel label = new JLabel("scale = 2.0");
            int value = (int)(magnifierPanel.scale * 2);
            final JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 1, 8, value);
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
                    float value = slider.getValue()/2f;
                    label.setText("scale = " + value);
                    magnifierPanel.setScale(value);
                }
            });

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2,2,2,2);
            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            panel.add(label, gbc);
            panel.add(slider, gbc);
            return panel;
        }
    }

    final class MagnifierPanel extends JPanel{ 
        BufferedImage image;
        Rectangle viewer, imageBounds; 
        float scale;
        Dimension targetSize;

        public MagnifierPanel(BufferedImage pic){ 
            loadImage(pic);
            viewer = new Rectangle(0, 0, 160, 160);
            imageBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            setScale(2.0f);
            setLayout(null);
            addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter(){
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
                    positionViewerAndImage();
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            //se lee el ancho de la imagen
            int imageWidth = image.getWidth(); 
            //se lee el alto de la imagen
            int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
            //tamaño de x (recuadro de la lupa)
            int x = (w - imageWidth)/2; 
            //tamaño de y (recuadro de la lupa)
            int y = (h - imageHeight)/2;
            //se pinta la lupa sobre la imagen con los tamaños de x/y
            g2.drawImage(image, x, y, this); 
            BufferedImage viewImage = getMagnifiedImage();
            if(viewImage != null)
                g2.drawImage(viewImage, viewer.x, viewer.y, this);
                //se le da el color rojo al borde de la lupa
                g2.setPaint(Color.red); 
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2f));
                g2.draw(viewer);
            }

        private BufferedImage getMagnifiedImage(){
            Point p = getSubimageLocation();
            int w = targetSize.width;
            int h = targetSize.height;
            BufferedImage target = null;
            try{
                target = image.getSubimage(p.x, p.y, w, h);
            }catch(RasterFormatException rfe){
                System.out.println("viewer out of bounds: " + rfe.getMessage() + "\n" +
                                   "\tx = " + p.x + "\t(x + w) = " + (p.x + w) + "\n" +
                                   "\ty = " + p.y + "\t(y + h) = " + (p.y + h));
                return target;
            }

            w = viewer.width;
            h = viewer.height;
            BufferedImage view = new BufferedImage(w, h, image.getType());
            Graphics2D g2 = view.createGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale);
            g2.drawRenderedImage(target, at);
            g2.dispose();
            return view;
        }

        private Point getSubimageLocation(){
            int w = targetSize.width;
            int h = targetSize.height;
            int x = viewer.x - imageBounds.x + (viewer.width - w)/2;
            int y = viewer.y - imageBounds.y + (viewer.height - h)/2;
            if(x + w > image.getWidth())
                x = image.getWidth() - w;
            if(y + h > image.getHeight())
                y = image.getHeight() - h;
            return new Point(x, y);
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            int w = image.getWidth() +
                        (scale > 1.0f ? viewer.width  - targetSize.width  : 0);
            int h = image.getHeight() +
                        (scale > 1.0f ? viewer.height - targetSize.height : 0);
            return new Dimension(w, h);
        }

        public void setScale(float f){
            scale = f;
            int width  = (int)(viewer.width / scale);
            int height = (int)(viewer.height / scale);
            targetSize = new Dimension(width, height);
            positionViewerAndImage();
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

        private void positionViewerAndImage(){
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            int x = (w - viewer.width)/2;
            int y = (h - viewer.height)/2;
            viewer.setLocation(x, y);
            x = (w - image.getWidth())/2;
            y = (h - image.getHeight())/2;
            imageBounds.setLocation(x, y);
            repaint();
        }

        public void setViewer(int x, int y){
            Point p = getLegalLocation(x, y);
            viewer.setLocation(p.x, p.y);
            repaint();
        }

        private Point getLegalLocation(int x, int y){
            int deltaW = (viewer.width - targetSize.width)/2;
            int deltaH = (viewer.height - targetSize.height)/2;
            if(x + deltaW < imageBounds.x)
                x = imageBounds.x - deltaW;
            if(x + viewer.width - deltaW > imageBounds.x + imageBounds.width)
                x = imageBounds.x + imageBounds.width - viewer.width + deltaW;
            if(y + deltaH < imageBounds.y)
                y = imageBounds.y - deltaH;
            if(y + viewer.height - deltaH > imageBounds.y + imageBounds.height)
                y = imageBounds.y + imageBounds.height - viewer.height + deltaH;
            return new Point(x, y);
        }


        public void loadImage(BufferedImage pic){ 

            String fileName ="Historial_Salidas/Bordes/" + pic;
            try{
              File archivo_imagen = new File (fileName);
              image = ImageIO.read(archivo_imagen);    
            }catch(MalformedURLException mue){  
              System.err.println("url: " + mue.getMessage());
            }catch(IOException ioe){
              System.err.println("read: " + ioe.getMessage());               
            }
         }
       }

    class MagnifierControl extends MouseInputAdapter{
        MagnifierPanel magnifierPanel;
        Point offset;
        boolean dragging;

        public MagnifierControl(MagnifierPanel mp){
            magnifierPanel = mp;
            offset = new Point();
            dragging = false;
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            if(magnifierPanel.viewer.contains(p)){
                offset.x = p.x - magnifierPanel.viewer.x;
                offset.y = p.y - magnifierPanel.viewer.y;
                dragging = true;
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
            dragging = false;
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            if(dragging){
                int x = e.getX() - offset.x;
                int y = e.getY() - offset.y;
                magnifierPanel.setViewer(x, y);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: donde declaras la variable pic?

Comment: Recuerdo que había otra pregunta sobre este tema y varios comentarios como el de @Crack81 ¿Por qué la borraste? Ahora empezarán a preguntarte lo mismo que ya te preguntaron ... Pudiste haber seguido alguno de los consejos que te daban en la otra pregunta y modificar lo que hiciera falta en la misma. Actuando así atrasas una solución y minusvaloras el esfuerzo de otros por ayudarte.

Comment: Los comentarios pasados no me ayudaron. Solo refactoricé la pregunta a ver si estaba mas clara y la borré para no tenerla repetida @A.Cedano La mayoría de los comentarios pasados eran referentes al que acabas de hacer mas que de la solucón del problema.

Comment: ¿No te ayudaron? Pues fíjate que empezamos de nuevo, porque recuerdo que te hice la misma pregunta que acaba de hacerte @Crack81 . Ahora tendrás que explicarle que defines la variable `pic` en otro sitio, etc, etc. Quiero decir que habiendo borrado la otra pregunta y planteando esta, empiezas de nuevo y verás que te preguntarán casi lo mismo que en aquella.

Comment: No, no me ayudaron por algo estoy de vuelta, sin embargo agradezco enormemente tu interés y los demás. Como te dije solo refactoricé la pregunta, quizás en la anterior no me expliqué de forma clara. @A.Cedano

Comment: Entendido. De todos modos, espero que encuentres pronto una solución óptima. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: Chicos ya veo el error... en la clase `Magnifying` cuando trato de agregar el `getUIPanel()` me sale el siguiente error: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Puedes agregar el stacktrace completo, para saber donde buscar

Comment: @Ajeno esta es la clase completa, ya me funciona la lectura de la imágen cuando la instancio desde la otra clase, el error que me ocurre ahora es en esta línea:  `frmLupe.getContentPane().add(getUIPanel(), "South");`. Me explico, de hecho no me da error, compila sin problems y  abre la ventana `frmLupe` pero en blanco

Comment: @CésarLandaeta no necesito la clase completa, sino el StackTrace, para poderte decir que está nulo parece que es magnifierPanel ya que lo instancias después de donde haces uso de getUIPanel()

Comment: @Ajeno `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at detector.Magnifying.getUIPanel(Magnifying.java:119)
 at detector.Magnifying.Magnifying(Magnifying.java:44)
 at detector.metodo$13.actionPerformed(metodo.java:366)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259) ....`

Answer (score 0):

Como te dije en el comentario todo parece indicar que es un problema de instanciación, ya que magnifierPanel lo llamas antes de su instanciación.

Lo que puedes hacer es instanciarlo antes del getUIPanel().

quedando así:

```
magnifierPanel = new MagnifierPanel(pic); <-- hasta aca se instancia
frmLupe.getContentPane().add(getUIPanel(), "South");
```

Prueba y me dices

```
public void Magnifying(BufferedImage pic){

       (pic.getScaledInstance(pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)); 
        JlImagen.setIcon(icon);
        JlImagen.repaint();
        PImagen.add(JlImagen);
        frmLupe.add(PImagen);


        frmLupe.setUndecorated(true);
        frmLupe.getRootPane().setBorder(border);
        frmLupe.setFocusable(true);
        //frmLupe.getContentPane().add(getUIPanel(), "South"); <-- Lo llamas aquí.
        frmLupe.getContentPane().add(JMenuMagnifying, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        frmLupe.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(magnifierPanel));
        frmLupe.setSize(620,650);
        frmLupe.setLocation(370,100);
        frmLupe.setVisible(true);


        JMenuMagnifying.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35,35));   
        JMenuMagnifying.add(JMenuMagnifying1);
        JMenuMagnifying.add(JMenuMagnifying2);
        JMenuMagnifying.add(JMenuMagnifying3);  

javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconos/verde_c.png")));
        JMenuMagnifying1.setToolTipText("Minimize window");
        JMenuMagnifying1.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){ 
                frmLupe.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
            }
        });


        JMenuMagnifying2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconos/amarillo_c.png"))); 
        JMenuMagnifying2.setToolTipText("Maximize window");
        JMenuMagnifying2.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){ 
                frmLupe.setExtendedState(frmLupe.getExtendedState()| FramePrincipal.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            }
        });


        JMenuMagnifying3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/iconos/rojo_c.png")));
        JMenuMagnifying3.setToolTipText("Close window"); 
        JMenuMagnifying3.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){ 
                frmLupe.setVisible(false); 
            }
        });


        frmLupe.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                 initialClick = e.getPoint();
                 frmLupe.getComponentAt(initialClick); 
            }
        });

        frmLupe.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

            //se localiza la ventana
            int thisX = frmLupe.getLocation().x;
            int thisY = frmLupe.getLocation().y;

            //se determina el movimiento del mouse
            int xMoved = (thisX + e.getX()) - (thisX + initialClick.x);
            int yMoved = (thisY + e.getY()) - (thisY + initialClick.y);

            //se mueve la ventana
            int X = thisX + xMoved;
            int Y = thisY + yMoved;
            frmLupe.setLocation(X, Y); 
        }
      });
         magnifierPanel = new MagnifierPanel(pic); <-- hasta aca se instancia
        control = new MagnifierControl(magnifierPanel);
        magnifierPanel.addMouseListener(control);
        magnifierPanel.addMouseMotionListener(control);
    }
```

Comment: read: `Can't read input file!
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at detector.MagnifierPanel.<init>(Magnifying.java:149)
 at detector.Magnifying.Magnifying(Magnifying.java:43)
 at detector.metodo$13.actionPerformed(metodo.java:366)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at ...`  DA ESTE ERROR

Comment: el error me está apuntando al metodo privado `private JPanel getUIPanel(){

            int value = (int)(magnifierPanel.scale * 2);` <--- AQUI

Comment: Si subiste la instanciación de la clase arriba del método frmLupe.getContentPane().add(getUIPanel(), "South"); la instanciación es cuando colocas el operador new

Comment: si coloco la instanciación antes de `frmLupe.getContentPane().add(getUIPanel(), "South");` me da error de lectura: `Can't read input file!` como el comentario anterior. En cambio, si la instancuación la dejo al final del metodo de la clase me marca error en: ` int value = (int)(magnifierPanel.scale * 2);`.

Comment: Bueno, lo correcto es corregir el Can't read input file, ya que el otro caso es imposible ayudarte (un null pointer exception causado porque no puedes instanciar un objeto ya que ese objeto no puede leer el input file). Así que donde declaras e instancias pic?

Comment: Ya lo ví. @Ajeno aún no funciona porque debo hacer unos cambios o averiguar otra forma de manera de no tocar el código ya hecho, pero ya se lo que causa el error. Muchas gracias por tus comentarios. RESUELTO!!!!!